# Git authentication over repository on private server

Tags: git, nginx

I am trying to make a website similar to github for my project for that
I am trying to setup private server for git on my local machine.

https://thenewstack.io/how-to-set-up-the-http-git-server-for-private-projects/

I followed the above tutorial

now the issue is that I can git clone/push any repository with any user credentials stored in htpasswd file where I would like that specific repo can be accessed via specific user only

can anyone please guide how should I approach the problem?

Comment: This is not a Linux programming question (you're not asking how to call `mmap` or `rclone` for instance); don't use the [tag:linux] tag. As for Git, it has *no authentication* in it; *you* must provide all authentication. How you wish to do that is up to you. StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask *design* questions: it's for nitpicky little detail questions. Consider softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com or some other stackexchange.com site for "how should I define authentication" questions.

Comment: the reason I included linux is because I followed tutorial in that , regarding my question I believe this is not first time of me asking something related to design paradigm, about your suggestion I am grateful I'll definitely look on those websites

Comment: The linux tag is for doing Linux-API-level programming. Click on any tag name, or even just hover your mouse over it in some cases, and you'll get more information about when to use the tag.